# MongoDB connection problem on localhost and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to run MongoDB inside NodeJS app, but whenever I try to run it, it throws this error:

```
\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421
      throw err
      ^
```

Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [localhost:5002] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5002
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
name: 'MongoError'

Since I'm a n00b in NodeJS, I hope someone could help me with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, which port is your MongoDB running? usually, it's 27017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you can check

1. check whether mongodb correctly installed on your system.
2. Use PORT=27017 instead of 5002 to connect to local mongodb server.
3. If problem still happens, then please check local mongodb server is active
   or not.